# Load Play! environment mode in another main process

Tags: heroku, playframework, play-framework-2.7

I have a Play application that contains a Main running another process. At Heroku, it is another dyno running this process.

I need to load the Mode `(Dev, Test, Prod)` which my Play application is running into the Main process `Application`, here:

`val app: Application = GuiceApplicationBuilder().build()`.

This is what I have:

```scala
object ConsumersApp {


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val app: Application = GuiceApplicationBuilder()
      .loadConfig(env => Configuration.load(env))
      .build()

      //...
  }

}
```

But `.loadConfig(env => Configuration.load(env))` actually returns `Mode.Test` even when in production environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `-main` option to the `target/universal/stage/bin` command in your `Procfile`. For example:

```
worker: target/universal/stage/bin/play-app -main com.example.MyClass
```

I'm not sure if there is a specification for this flag, but [the code is on Github](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/f39bf3bf4a41b11430afa103a7904e921bd2c0a6/src/main/resources/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/scripts/bash-template#L196)